# Jquery insert span into input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a simple tagging system for an text input field, here's what it looks like.

[image: Screenshot of tagging system]

At the moment, the next tag is being added before the input field, but I'd like it to appear within the input field, so that if the users hits backsapce, it will delete the tag.  If that makes sense.  I'm not sure how to get the span to appear inside of the input field, here's the code:

```
<div id="formWrapper" class="ui-widget">
    <form id="searchForm" action="#">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Test search form</legend>
            <span>Search</span>
            <div id="searchBoxDiv" class="ui-helper-clearfix">
                <button type="button" id="savedSearchButton">Test</button>
                <input id="searchBox" type="text" autocomplete="false">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

function addSearchTerm(e, ui) {
            var searchTerm = ui.item.value;
            var span = $("<span>").text(searchTerm);
            var a = $("<a>").addClass("remove").addClass("testclass").attr({
                href: "javascript:",
                title: "Remove " + searchTerm
            }).text("x").appendTo(span);

           span.insertBefore("#searchBox");
        }
```

I've tried various combinations of `insert`, `append` but I don't seem to be able to get anything inside of the input, except text.  I'm guessing I'll have to do something where the input field is within another , but I'm really not sure how.

Thanks

Comment: That's how input works, you can't insert other than text or unicodes , perhaps there is a work around using `contenteditable` attribute.

Comment: You cannot achieve what you need with standard HTML input elements. You need to emulate visual appearance if input field via set of DIV and other elements being styled just like the input field. See jQuery some plugin e.g. Select2 with pillbox https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#multi-select-boxes-pillbox